# AppleScript: How to pass subroutine parameters to another subroutine

Tags: recursion, applescript

I have an AppleScript that I'm trying to modularize for future use. Working fine: a script that steps through nested Finder folders recursively. What I want: that script to call *another* subroutine with its own parameters.

Sample code (with a working recurse function), where I'm using commented pseudocode for the parts I need help with:

```
on recurseFolders_runSubroutine(thisItem, subName, subParameters, notify)
    global itemcount
    try
        set itemcount to itemcount + 1
    on error
        set itemcount to 1
    end try

    tell application "Finder"
        if notify then display notification ("Recursing into folder ") & name of thisItem with title "Entering Folder"
        if kind of thisItem is "Folder" then
            set subItems to every item in thisItem
            set countItems to count subItems
            repeat with i from 1 to countItems
                set subItem to item i of subItems
                my recurseFolders_runSubroutine(subItem, subName, subParameters, notify, itemcount)
            end repeat
        else
            -- tell script ("subName" & .scpt) to [call subroutine named subName with the parameters, presumably passed in a list]
        end if
    end tell
end recurseFolders_runSubroutine
```

I tried it with a few variations on run script with a text string to call the function, but then I can't pass the list of subparameters as a list. Am I missing something?

Comment: The syntax for calling a script's `subName` handler is e.g. `tell myScript to subName("howdy")`. There is no `eval` in AppleScript; you can't turn an arbitrary string into that call.

Comment: You could construct the script as a string and tell `osascript` to compile and run it thru the `do shell script` command

Comment: That would require a lot of coercion of things into strings, but yes, I see that as a possible workaround.